How to correctly test error messages from Blob error responses in Angular unit tests?
I'm working on an Angular application where I need to export data to a CSV file. I've implemented error handling to log specific error messages from Blob responses. However, I'm facing an issue with the unit test for this error handling.
Here's the relevant part of my Angular component:
export class DataExportComponent {
  isLoading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  dataFilters = {};

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private logger: LoggerService) {}

  exportData() {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
    const request = this.dataFilters;

    this.dataService
      .exportDataResponse(request)
      .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading$.next(false)))
      .subscribe(
        (response: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
          // Logic for handling successful response (omitted for brevity)
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          let errorMessage = 'An error occurred while exporting data. Please try again later.';

          if (error.error instanceof Blob) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
              try {
                const errorJson = JSON.parse(reader.result as string);
                errorMessage = errorJson.message || errorMessage;
              } catch (e) {}

              this.logger.error(errorMessage);
            };
            reader.readAsText(error.error);
          } else {
            this.logger.error(errorMessage);
          }
        }
      );
  }
}

Here's the unit test for the error handling:
describe('DataExportComponent', () => {
// general initializations

  describe('error handling', () => {
    it('should log error message for non-Blob error', fakeAsync(() => {
      const mockError: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: 'error',
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'Server Error'
      });

      dataServiceSpy.exportDataResponse.and.returnValue(throwError(mockError));

      component.exportData();
      tick();

      expect(loggerSpy.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        'An error occurred while exporting data. Please try again later.'
      );
    }));

    it('should log error message from Blob error response', fakeAsync(() => {
      const errorBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ message: 'Specific error message' })], {
        type: 'application/json'
      });

      const mockError: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: errorBlob,
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'Bad Request'
      });

      dataServiceSpy.exportDataResponse.and.returnValue(throwError(mockError));

      spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsText').and.callFake(function (this: FileReader, blob: Blob) {
        this.onload!({
          target: {
            result: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Specific error message' })
          }
        } as ProgressEvent<FileReader>);
      });

      component.exportData();
      tick();

      expect(loggerSpy.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Specific error message');
    }));
  });
});

The problem I'm facing is with the test for logging error messages from Blob error responses. The reader.result is always null, and the error message is not being logged as expected. Here's the part of the code where the issue occurs:
if (error.error instanceof Blob) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    try {
      const errorJson = JSON.parse(reader.result as string);
      errorMessage = errorJson.message || errorMessage;
    } catch (e) {}

    this.logger.error(errorMessage);
  };
  reader.readAsText(error.error);
}

The reader.result is null every time, and I can't figure out why. Could anyone help me understand what might be going wrong and how to fix it?
Additional Details:
Angular version: 14
Testing framework: Jasmine
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I guess I would outsource the FileReader creation to a Factory of some kind. Otherwise you are unable to mock the behavior of "FileReader" and the prototype manipulation seems rather hacky.
